# Typescript - Ensure that id is present in array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Store in which I want to manage ids properly. Say I have the following Posts Store:

```js
type Post = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body?: string;
}

type Store = {
  postId: number | null;
  posts: Post[];
  addPost: (post: Omit<Post, "id">) => Promise<void>;
  updatePost: (id: number, post: Partial<Post>) => Promise<void>;
};
```

If a post is selected, the postId is set to the selected post id. I want to tell typescript  that this postId is always / should always be in posts. So I can be sure that if I want to find the proper post, it's always there.

Is there any way in typescript to do this?

Something like this:

```
type Store = {
  postId: (number in StoreType.posts.key<"id">) | null;
  posts: Post[];
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Just for clarification - postId should always be a number of... what? An object instance of the StoreType? Also, what is `StoreType` in your example. As far as I am concerned, it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. There is no way for the transpiler to know what `id`'s are present in the Store - let alone transpile it to a type. TL:DR - There's no way to tell typescript that there should *always* be a matching post to the `id`.

Comment: I don't think TS can help you with that, maybe you can write a uitility method that will warn you that the id is not present in the object, but it must only run when the postId is invoked (or about to be used). This is especially important as you might be using derived data, and the id is initially undefined. Hope this helos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this.

This depends on runtime dynamics which are out of scope for TS to check. There is no way for TS to figure out that when you're setting the `id` you are also having an item in the array with that id.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is define your posts [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so the compiler can infer the post ids at compile time. However, it's not possible to do that kind of type checking at runtime.

```
const posts = [
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Post 5",
    body: "some description"
  },
  {
    id: 42069,
    title: "Post 42069",
    body: "some description"
  },
  {
    id: 666,
    title: "Post 666",
    body: "some description"
  }
] as const;

type Store = {
  postId: (typeof posts)[number]["id"]; // 3 | 42069 | 666
  posts: Post[];
  addPost: (post: Omit<Post, "id">) => Promise<void>;
  updatePost: (id: number, post: Partial<Post>) => Promise<void>;
};
```